# Authorize, AuthorizeCallback undefined for the type Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

Well, as said in the title, I get two errors on the class where I put the SSO code saying:

1) "The method Authorize is undefined for the type Facebook"...
2) "The constructor Facebook is undefined"...

I get the same error for AuthorizeCallback...

I don't know what to do... I followed the tutorial that "FB" created ("Android Tutorial")...

This is the code:

```
package my.package.namespace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

public class Facebook extends Activity {

    Facebook fbclient = new Facebook("myappid");


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        fbclient.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        fbclient.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: have add com folder from fb sdk in project src?

Comment: Yeah I added the entire folder...

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename your activity to something else (other than "Facebook").

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924453/how-to-integrate-facebook-api-in-android-application/9924681#9924681), which contains a working example.

Just download Project and import in Eclipse and try to run check one thing before app Run is that reference library is properly added or not.

Comment: The library is properly referred... I've done everything you wrote and everything that has been written in the tutorial on FB... Still I get those error messages

Comment: see buddy you have to import only folder named HackBook ok and if you are getting errors just comment them if they are unnecessary .